# flash as3 how to force moviclip code to obey interface

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, oop, interface, movieclip

very often I like to have my movieclip code ***inside*** the movieclip (on a layer *on the timeline*).

Is there a way to make movieclip code implement an interface (eg. the timeline-code implements the interface)?

Comment: What do you mean by 'obey interface'? To implement an Interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clean approach would be, creating a symbol and implementing a class, which extends MovieClip and implements the desired interface. In this class, you implement the views behavior.

Time line code will always have to be decorated by the interface, you can not implement the interface via timeline code.

Comment: ... but this approach does not force the code on the mc's timeline to obey/implement the interface.

Comment: No, as i said the clean approach. No code on the timeline is best practice.

Comment: Florian, it depends on what you want to do, and your level of development skill. 

If you want to easily pass around movieclips from one app to another, or from one developer to another, then timeline-based code is very convenient, and clean ( being required to pass multiple pieces (movieclip + .as file) for the sake of a single thing is not 'as clean as possible').

Comment: It always depends on what you want to do. And just for sharing single clips, this might be ok. But this solution simply doesn't scale. And sharing the designs + code is in general the preferred way of working. And just to answer your question: time line code will always have to be decorated by the interface, you can not implement the interface via timeline code.

Comment: could you move this "you can not implement the interface via timeline code." to your answer ... then i can approve it.